# Oat++ response method readBodyToDto example

Tags: oat++

Has anybody used objectMapper to parse the body of a oatpp::web::client::RequestExecutir::Response using method readBodyToDto. I am building a REST API client and I haven't been able to map the returned object into my dto. Here's the piece of code that I am struggling with:

```
void GoRestApi::getUser(const std::shared_ptr<GoRestApiClient>& client)
{
   auto response = client->doGetUser(2600);
   oatpp::String contentType = response->getHeader("Content-Type");
// auto userDto = response->readBodyToDto<oatpp::Object<UserDto>>(objectMapper);
   auto data = response->readBodyToString();

   OATPP_LOGD(TAG, "[doGetUser] data='%s'", data->c_str());
}
```

I commented out the line that I can't get even to compile.
If you have some code snippet that you can share, I'd love it. Thanks a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me

```
    auto objectMapper = oatpp::parser::json::mapping::ObjectMapper::createShared();
    auto dtmResponseDTO = response->readBodyToDto<oatpp::Object<DtmResponseDTO>>(objectMapper);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

May be you should import or initialize the objectMapper to compile.
I got another issue when deserializing too, when it seems to be blocked on readBodyToDto

I also tried readFromString

```
auto objectMapper = oatpp::parser::json::mapping::ObjectMapper::createShared();

auto reponseIdDto = objectMapper->readFromString<oatpp::Object<ReponseIdDto>>(response->readBodyToString());
```